# Why does this give me an error, and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
line = ' '
while line != '':
    line = input('Line: ')
    phonic = line.split()
    start = phonic[0]
    start_4 = phonic [3]
    a = start[0]
    if start_4.startswith(a):
        print('Good!')
    else:
        print("That's not right!")
```

I think I know, since `line = ''`, phonic is trying to split it, but there's nothing there, how do I fix that?

Comment: What error? Post the full traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to have a conditional statement before you do any other things:

```
line = ' '
while line:
    line = input('Line: ')
    if not line:
        break # break out of the loop before raising any KeyErrors
    phonic = line.split()
    start = phonic[0]
    start_4 = phonic [3]
    a = start[0]
    if start_4.startswith(a):
        print('Good!')
    else:
        print("That's not right!")
```

Note that `while line != ''` can simply be shortened to `while line`, because `''` is considered `False`, so `!= False` is `== True`, and this can be eradicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while True` to create an infinite loop, and use `break` to end it. Now you can end the loop as soon as you read an empty line and not fail when trying to address elements that won't exist:

```
while True:
    line = input('Line: ')
    if not line:
        break

    phonic = line.split()
    start = phonic[0]
    start_4 = phonic [3]
    a = start[0]
    if start_4.startswith(a):
        print('Good!')
    else:
        print("That's not right!")
```

Note you don't even have to test more than just `if line`; an empty string is considered false in a boolean test like `if`.